# Use email addresses with plus signs in Thunderbird

Tags: email, thunderbird

It's nowadays normal to differentiate an email account by adding tags, such as `janedoe+work@example.com`, `janedoe+private@example.com` and so on. Depending on the email provider, all these mails should be forwarded to `janedoe@example.com`, but contain the tag (`work`, `private`) in the header.

How can I work with this metadata in Thunderbird? Is it possible to e.g. sort or group by these tags? Is it possible to set up a filter that will move such addresses to respective subfolders?

Comment: Sending an email with such a tag got me in Thunderbird the error of Invalid address.

Comment: Do you want one filter that would sort *all* tags? Otherwise the existing "To or Cc"  filter should work fine.

Comment: Aside for future readers: not all providers support this, and not all providers that do support this will add headers to the message. Its common name is ["subaddressing"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Email_address#Subaddressing) a.k.a. "plus addressing".

Comment: @Arjan: I wasn't talking about an additional header, but about the regular `To:` header which contains the full address as the sender entered.

Comment: I understand, @grawity, but my comment was not a response to yours :-) I had not even read your comment; a +1 for that now; it might make a good answer too! :-)